# Which normalization method for different units (zero, negative, etc.)

Tags: standard-deviation, normalization, scales, mean

Commonly, **normalization** of ratings seems to mean adjusting values measured on different scales to a notionally **common scale**.

I have different metrics that measure different **performance aspects** of a server. I want to **aggregate these values**. The problem is:

- The values are on **different scale types** (interval and ratio scale)
- The values have different minimum and maximum values

  Most of them are between $0.0$ and $1.0$, where $0$ means **complete absence** of the measured attribute and $1$ means the attribute is maximized to the best characteristic it can gain.
- One of the ratio scale values can be $[0, \infty]$. Theoretically, speaking, practically something around $500$. More is here better $0$ is absence, too.
- The interval scale can be **negative, positive and zero**. Zero does not mean, absence. The less, the better. The more, the worse.

How do I approach this? I need to aggregate the results and feel a bit lost. I see two options here.

1. Use a normalization, but which one? Ideally I would all map to $[0,1]$ so I can present them as percentage, although that would be unprecise for the one ratio and the one interval.

   I know **min-max scaling** (feature scaling?), but is that appropriate? What about **z-score?** With z-score however, it seems I will land again on a negative-positive scale.
2. Use a tendency to aggregate, arithmetic mean (needs normalization), geometric mean (false semantic on zero results), **adjusted geometric mean**, etc.

How should I approach this, can someone advise me?